# Поиск в условных операторах

Tags: python, for

```
for i in db.user_all_db():
   if 'web3' in i[2].lower():
      print(f'{i[0]}|{i[2].lower()}')
```

у меня есть такой кусок кода мне оно нужно чтобы я находил нужного пользователя с помощью ключевых слов таких как ['web3',.......] их может быть бесконечное кол-во
как мне можно сделать так чтобы их находить
не обязательно через условные операторы если есть библиотеки то можно и с помощью них

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно встроенных средств питона, используйте метод `any` и *генераторное сокращение*:

```py
lst = ['web3', 'text', 'http']

for i in db.user_all_db():
   if any(x in i[2].lower() for x in lst):
      print(f'{i[0]}|{i[2].lower()}')
```